# i want to remove tag in xml when it is repeating multiple times

Tags: shell-script, html

I want to comment particular tag with particular value from xml when it is repeating multiple times

example:

```
<t1>
<t2>hi<t2/>
<t1/>
<t1>
<t2>hello<t2/>
<t1/>
<t1>
<t2>byee<t2/>
<t1/>
```

I want it as

```
<t1>
<t2>hi<t2/>
<t1/>
<!--<t1>
<t2>hello<t2/>
<t1/> -->
<t1>
<t2>byee<t2/>
<t1/>
```

Comment: I don't understand the example, you've got 3 <t1> containers, and you're commenting out the middle one.  You might need to give a more complete example.  Also, are you just processing these as text files from the shell?

Answer (score 0):

XML is a strict, multiline format, where the nesting of tags carries meaning. You should use a tool able to parse, interpret and recreate it, not snip around with line-oriented tools. Not saying it is easy, far from it.